# Run the cucumber automation script in ror application I got the following error:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm receiving the following error while run the cucumber automation script in my ror application.
Here's my step definition.rb file:

```
When("I upload a file") do
  attach_file(:csv_file, "#{Rails.root}/rec.csv", make_visible: true)
  sleep(2)
  click_button 'open'
end
```

I run the cucumber by using rake cucumber, the following error is occur:

> Scenario: Uploading a valid csv file       # features/user.feature:18
>       Given I visit the file upload page       # features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:45
>       When I upload a file                     # features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:50
>         Unable to find file field :csv_file that is not disabled (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
>         ./features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:51:in `"I upload a file"'
>         features/user.feature:20:in`When I upload a file'
>       Then the number of records are displayed # features/step_definitions/user_step.rb:58
>
> Failing Scenarios: cucumber features/user.feature:18 # Scenario:
>   Uploading a valid csv file

I will be thankful if you can help me fixing this problem?

Comment: Apparently, there is no `:csv_file` field on that page.

Comment: I need to upload a csv file through choose file button, how I fetch my csv file  from my local window